# Loop variable is not appending file

Tags: ansible

When i use blockinfile loop to append /etc/environment file it only adds last key and value of item from loop variable rather then adding all of it.

I am trying to modify files using Blockinfile module in roles main.yml:

```
- name: Add proxy to global /etc/environments
blockinfile:
 path: "/etc/environment"
 block: |
  export {{item.key}}={{item.value}}
loop: "{{proxy_details}}"
```

my vars/main.yaml looks like this:

```
proxy_details:
- key: http_proxy
  value: "http://"{{ProxyHost}}":"{{ProxyPort}}""
- key: https_proxy
  value: "http://"{{ProxyHost}}":"{{ProxyPort}}""
```

my group_vars/all looks like this:

```
ProxyHost: test.com
ProxyPort: 9999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the last example in the documentaion at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html. You need to use a custom marker for each item so Ansible knows where each one is in the file to replace it.

Per documentation note:

> When using ‘with_*’ loops be aware that if you do not set a unique mark the block will be overwritten on each iteration.

The example is:

```
- name: Add mappings to /etc/hosts
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/hosts
    block: |
      {{ item.ip }} {{ item.name }}
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ item.name }}"
  loop:
    - { name: host1, ip: 10.10.1.10 }
    - { name: host2, ip: 10.10.1.11 }
    - { name: host3, ip: 10.10.1.12 }
```

You could modify yours to be:

```
- name: Add proxy to global /etc/environments
  blockinfile:
    path: "/etc/environment"
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK FOR {{item.key}}"
    block: |
      export {{item.key}}={{item.value}}
  loop: "{{proxy_details}}"
```